# Python tweepy track

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to get all tweets with a keyword using Tweepy, and it's not returning anything on certain keywords. For example, if use Obama as the keyword I get many tweets, if I use Arduino I don't get anything back here is my code.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_token=""
access_token_secret=""

class Listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

stream = Stream(auth, Listener())
stream.filter(track=['arduino'])
```

What am I doing wrong?
Also, can I filter RT somehow?

Answer (score 1):

`Stream()` is for *real-time* tweet collection.  The reason you're not collecting any tweets about `arduino` is because it is tweeted about comparably much less than a famous person like Obama (ex.  when I tried, I got 5 tweets about Obama within 2 seconds, but it took me 10 minutes to collect a single tweet that mentioned Arduino.  Keep in mind that the filters are case-sensitive too.  To get non-real-time tweets you need to use [.search()](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=search#API.search). of a `tweepy.API` object.

Like this:

```
twAPI = tweepy.API(auth)
list_of_tweets = twAPI.search("Arduino")
```

I hope this helps!

**EDIT:**  IDK if tweepy is compatible with REST 1.1 (mine threw some warnings using version 1.0).  Check out [Python Twitter Tools](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter) if tweepy fails you.